# Hibernate search: Indexed data with Ngram filter and while searching it gives incorrect result due to tokenizing while querying

Tags: java, hibernate, elasticsearch, lucene, hibernate-search

I have an analyzer with this configuration,

```
searchMapping//
        .analyzerDef(BaseEntity.CUSTOM_SEARCH_INDEX_ANALYZER, WhitespaceTokenizerFactory.class)//
        .filter(LowerCaseFilterFactory.class)//
        .filter(ASCIIFoldingFilterFactory.class)//
        .filter(NGramFilterFactory.class).param("minGramSize", "1").param("maxGramSize", "200");
```

This is how my entity field is configured

```
@Field(analyzer = @Analyzer(definition = CUSTOM_SEARCH_INDEX_ANALYZER))
private String bookName;
```

This is how I create a search query

```
queryBuilder.keyword().onField(prefixedPath).matching(matchingString).createQuery()
```

I have an entity with value bookName="Gulliver" and another entity with bookName="xGulliver";

If I tried to search with data `bookName = xG` then am getting both entities where I would expect entity only with `bookName="xGulliver"`;
Also looked on the query that is produced by hibernate-search.

> Executing Lucene query '+(+(+(+(
>           bookName:x 
>           bookName:xg 
>           bookName:g))))

Above Lucene query is prepared using `BooleanJunction::must` conditions by Lucene I guess which means it should match all the conditions.
Still why its giving me both entity data. I dont understand here.

I can also override the analyzer while querying by having KeywordTokenizer instead of NGramFilterFactory but this is like I have to override for each and every field before creating QueryBuilder which doesnt looks good because then I have to override all index fields which I have about 100 fields and some are dynamic fields and I create individual query for each field.

Is there any other way to override the analyzer in 5.11 version or is it handled in some other way in hibernate-search 6.x version in easier way?

Hibernate versions that I use are,

> hibernate-search-elasticsearch, hibernate-search-orm = 5.11.4.Final

Answer (score 2):

> Above Lucene query is prepared using BooleanJunction::must conditions by Lucene I guess which means it should match all the conditions. Still why its giving me both entity data. I dont understand here.

When you create a `keyword` query using Hibernate Search, the string passed to that query is analyzed, and if there are multiple tokens, Hibernate Search creates a boolean query with one "should" clause for each token. You can see it here " bookName:x bookName:xg bookName:g": there is no "+" sign before "bookName", which means those are not "must" clauses, they are "should" clauses.

> I can also override the analyzer while querying by having KeywordTokenizer instead of NGramFilterFactory but this is like I have to override for each and every field before creating QueryBuilder which doesnt looks good because then I have to override all index fields which I have about 100 fields and some are dynamic fields and I create individual query for each field.

True, that's annoying.

> Is there any other way to override the analyzer in 5.11 version

In 5.11, I don't think there is any other way to override analyzers.

If necessary and if you're using the Lucene backend, I believe you should be able to bypass the Hibernate Search DSL just for this specific query:

- Get the analyzer you want: something like `Analyzer analyzer = fullTextSession.getSearchFactory().getAnalyzer("myAnalyzerWithoutNGramTokenFilter")`.
- Analyze the search terms: call `analyzer.tokenStream(...)` and use the `TokenStream` as appropriate. You'll get a list of tokens.
- Create the Lucene `Query`: essentially it will be a boolean query with one `TermQuery` for each token.
- Pass the resulting `Query` to Hibernate Search as usual.

> or is it handled in some other way in hibernate-search 6.x version in easier way?

It's dead simple in [Hibernate Search 6](https://hibernate.org/search/releases/6.0/) and later. There are two solutions:

- Implicitly: in your mapping, you can specify not only an [analyzer](https://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/search/6.0/reference/en-US/html_single/#mapper-orm-directfieldmapping-analyzer) (using `@FullTextField(analyzer = "myAnalyzer")`), but also a ["search" analyzer](https://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/search/6.0/reference/en-US/html_single/#mapper-orm-directfieldmapping-search-analyzer) using `@FullTextField(analyzer = "myAnalyzer", searchAnalyzer = "mySearchAnalyzer")`. The "default" analyzer will be used when indexing, while the "search" analyzer will be used when searching (querying).
- Explicitly: at query time, you can override the analyzer on a given predicate by calling `.analyzer("mySearchAnalyzer")` while building the predicate. There is one example [in this section of the documentation](https://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/search/6.0/reference/en-US/html_single/#mapper-orm-directfieldmapping-analyzer).

Note however that dynamic fields are not supported yet in Hibernate Search 6: [HSEARCH-3273](https://hibernate.atlassian.net/browse/HSEARCH-3273).

Comment: Thanks for your valuable comment. Hibernate-search 6 looks awesome with these features.

As a workaround I have configured only the normalizer with ASCII filter and lowercase filter and for partial matches am using wildcard query. I definitely prefer solution 1.

Looking forward for hibernate-search 6.x version release.